# Acumatica T100(Setting ComboBox at Runtime) enable property not available for edstatus

Tags: acumatica

I'm having an issue following this lesson exercise [here's an image of the instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvVPH.png). When I have the edStatus field selected the enable property is not available for me to change.[Here is an image of the layout editor with edStatus selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fekq5.png) Other fields have the enable ExtProperty but this specific field I can't locate it to complete the exercise. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that you can set the enabled property even if not listed via the layout editor through the source code. Hopes this helps anyone else stuck on this issue.